# Run two queries in one MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to read values from two tables in a MySQL trigger but whereas running one select query works running two queries in one trigger seems to be rejected. Can you suggest workarounds?

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `CreateCommunityPost` 
AFTER INSERT ON `ms_community_post_cpy` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE atlas_id INT;
    DECLARE atlas_city VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE ctnt VARCHAR(150);
    DECLARE image_url VARCHAR(150);

(select id, city into  atlas_id, atlas_city from ms_atlas order by rand() limit 1)

(select title, img_url into ctnt, image_url from img_tmp WHERE id = NEW.id)
INSERT INTO `ms_community_post_cpy` (`user_id`, `content`, `cover`, `type`, `is_open`, `top`, `order`, `status`, `add_time`, `title`, `good`, `is_check`, `tag_id`, `is_vip`, `is_recommend`, `click`, `city`, `search_num`)
VALUES (atlas_id, ctnt, null, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '', (select floor(0+ RAND() * 10000)), 1, 60, 0, 0, (select floor(0+ RAND() * 10000)), atlas_city, 0) ;

END

$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: every statement needs to be terminated - your selects aren't ,why the pointless brackets?..AND you can't insert to the same table the trigger is on. Need more help post sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: If you want to return multiple tables selected from the trigger then you can create a temporary table and insert select data into that table and just on select query would be there and that table would be a temporary table. 
I don't know but that would be helpful for you.